# Filter by a transformed list, then untransform the result

Tags: haskell, homework

Both exercises have a common pattern of "filter by a transformed list, then untransform the result". See `skip` and `localMaxima`.

```
-- exercise 1
skips :: [a] -> [[a]]
skips xs = map (\n -> skip n xs) [1..(length xs)]

skip :: Integral n => n -> [a] -> [a]
skip n xs = map snd $ filter (\x -> (fst x) `mod` n == 0) (zip [1..] xs)


--exercise 2
isLocalMaximum :: Integral a => (a,a,a) -> Bool
isLocalMaximum (a,b,c) = b > a && b > c

sliding3 :: [a] -> [(a,a,a)]
sliding3 xs@(a:b:c:_) = (a,b,c) : sliding3 (tail xs)
sliding3 _ = []

localMaxima :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]
localMaxima xs = map proj2 $ filter isLocalMaximum (sliding3 xs)
  where proj2 (_,b,_) = b

-- *Main> filter isLocalMaximum (sliding3 [1,5,2,6,3])
-- [(1,5,2),(2,6,3)]
```

My instincts say that I could implement both of these something like this:

```
localMaxima' :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]
localMaxima' xs = filterBy isLocalMaximum sliding3 xs
```

if only I could implement filterBy

```
filterBy :: (b -> Bool) -> ([a] -> [b]) -> [a] -> [a]
filterBy p f as = as'
  where indexedAs = zipWith (,) [0..] as
        indexedBs = zipWith (,) [0..] (f as)
        indexedBs' = filter p indexedBs     -- doesn't typecheck; how can we teach p about the tuples?
        indexes = map fst indexedBs
        as' = map (\i -> snd (indexedAs !! i)) indexes
```

It's also slower than just writing out a fold. Is this all a bad idea? I've always considered `fold` a low level recursion operator and always try to structure in terms of higher level `map` and `filter` but maybe I am misunderstanding.

My Haskell level is: understand LYAH but not written much code.

This is a homework to CIS 194 (2013 version) (though I am not taking the class, I am working through the material on my own)

Answer (score 1):

### Exercise 1

If you have a lambda (or any function) of type `(a,b)->c`, instead of writting it like this `(\x->...)`, you can write it like this `(\(x,y)->...)`. It will remove the need of calling `fst` like in your skip function. You should change the name skip too, because it already exist in the prelude and it's kinda unclear because they have different meaning. I would call it something like `skipEvery`

### Exercise 2

`as` is a keyword in Haskell, used for module importation. It will compile if you use it as a variable, but if you a text editor with syntax highlighting, it will be weird

> My instincts say that I could implement both of these something like
>   this:
>
> ```
> localMaxima' :: Integral a => [a] -> [a] 
> localMaxima' xs = filterBy isLocalMaximum sliding3 xs
> ```

Your instinct wasn't wrong, but there is an alternative to filterBy, which is [`mapMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe). The resulting code would be something like this

```
whenMaybe p x = if p x then Just x else Nothing
localMaxima' = mapMaybe (whenMaybe isLocalMaximum) . sliding3
```

You should use `zip` instead of `zipWith (,)`, because both operations are equivalent